# a simple django template error 

Tags: python, django, templates

this is my code :

```
var next_lat={{ o|return_next_element:forloop.counter0|return_element:'latitude'|floatformat:"6"}}
var next_lng={{ o|return_next_element:forloop.counter0|return_element:'longitude'|floatformat:"6"}}
```

and it show this error :

```
return_element requires 1 arguments, 0 provided
```

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you're not really giving us much to go on here. but could it be that return_next_element returns nothing, and therefore return_element has nothing to work with?